# Why does deserializeUntyped interpret Strings starting with digits as Integers

Tags: json, deserialize, data-types, typecast

This code

```
List<String> ls = new List<String>{'32', '4text', 'text5'};
Object obj;
for (String s : ls){
    try{ 
        obj = JSON.deserializeUntyped(s); 
        System.debug(s + ' becomes ' + obj);
        System.debug(obj instanceof Integer);
    }
    catch (JsonException e) { 
        System.debug(s + ' is not json' );
    }
}
```

returns, or rather displays, to be exact

```
32 becomes 32
true
4text becomes 4
true
text5 is not json
```

I would expect *4text* to be interpreted as String, not Integer.
Maybe it's how JSON works but I didn't find it in RFC 8529 (I admit I just had a quick look)... Or is it a bug ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A String in [JSON](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) is always wrapped in double quotes but your code does not provide those. Perhaps the RFC specifies that number parsing discards unrecognised trailing characters, hence your result?

Try out:

```
List<String> ls = new List<String>{'"32"', '"4text"', '"text5"'};
```

Comment: You're totally right. Unfortunately when you get data from external APIs you sometimes -if not often- get data like {"n" : "12", "hash" : "32af80d1"}. If you want *n* to be understood as the number 12, you'll have the hash understood as the number 32. The solution is to use well coded APIs but sometimes you just can't...

Comment: In case anyone else gets the issue, you can check the string is really a number with Pattern.matches('^-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?([eE][-+]?\\d+)?$', serializedString), this way you won't deserialize as numbers strings like '32ef' or '42 years old'